# Set fields as missing when importing from CSV

Tags: csv, sas

```
data myout;
infile "&path.\regex.csv" dlm=',';
input fname $ format1 $ format2 $ format3 $; 
run;
```

My CSV looks like:

```
field_name, format1, format2, format3
bank_acct, /\d{8}/,,
sort_code, /\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}/,,
bank_name, string,,
credit_card, /\d{16}/,,
customer_id, /\s{2}\d{11}/, /\s{1}\d{12}/, /\d{12}/
...
```

How can I set the fields to missing where they don't have a second and third format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `DSD` add `TRUNCOVER` options to your **INFILE** statement:

```
data myout;
   infile "&path.\regex.csv" dlm=',' DSD TRUNCOVER;
   input fname $ format1 $ format2 $ format3 $; 
run;
```

Data rows that are empty will be set to missing automatically.

Comment: I'd actually recommend MISSOVER for this, not TRUNCOVER.  Both will work, but MISSOVER is more clearly relevant for the specific expectation here, so it would be clearer to other users.

Comment: What about if the field is a character type? It appears to not set missing then. Would the only thing to then go over with an if statemetn and set them to missing manually?

Comment: @user1068446 not sure what you mean; all the variables in your question **ARE** character.  But the data type does not matter; your problem was related to how the `INPUT` statement works.  If you need help with something else, please ask a new question.